# Nginx Rewrite Rules for rewriting html files to php not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite all the HTML file to PHP files in nginx.So i entered the below rule in my nginx conf file.

```
location ~ \.html$
{      rewrite (.*).html$ /$1.php;
}
```

But it doesnt works, so I tried putting the rewrite rule inbelwo location but even this doesnt works.

```
location / {
  rewrite (.*).html$ /$1.php;
  rewrite admin/$ /admin/index.php;
  rewrite ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /productlist.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2;
  rewrite ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /productlist.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&brand=$3;
  rewrite ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/buy/$ /productdetails.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&product=$3&id=$4;
  rewrite ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/buy$ /productdetails.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&product=$3&id=$4;
  rewrite admin/internalattacment/(.*) /download.php/$1;
  rewrite admin/report_bug/(.*) /download.php/$1;
}
```

But when I put the rewrite rule like this its picked up by nginx

```
location ~ .*.()$ {
  rewrite (.*).html$ /$1.php;
}
```

Can somebody please tell me why rewrite rules are not picked up from first 2 locations?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the location.

```
location ~ \.html$
```

matches only ".html", not "anything.html"
try

```
location ~ /(.*).html$
```

Comment: nopes .. it didn't worked. Same rule for php i.e. "location ~ \.php$" works fine.